# Table View Height Dynamically

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift5, custom-sections

I implemented expandable sections on my UITableView and now my problem is that when the UIViewController loads the table there are rows below the section.

Not expanded:

[image]

Expanded:

[image]

I want the `UITableView` to have no rows if the section is not expanded so I can set another `UIView` below the section. When the section is expanded the `UIView` should disappear and the table view to be presented on the whole screen.

Comment: Add your code in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply implement the `viewForFooterInSection` and return an empty view.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView(frame: .zero)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView()
}
```

just use this code it will remove your unwanted rows.